# Wrong Enum index when serializing an Enum field (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization, enums

In Unity3D, I have two Enums:

```
public enum GlobalColor
{
    Player,
    PlayerFX1,
    PlayerFX2,
    Ennemy,
    EnnemyFX1,
    EnnemyFX2,
    Background,
    BackgroundParticles1,
    BackgroundParticles2,
    Button,
    InactiveButton
}
```

```
public enum ColorName
{
    Player,
    PlayerFX1,
    PlayerFX2,
    Ennemy_1,
    EnnemyFX1_1,
    EnnemyFX2_1,
    Ennemy_2,
    EnnemyFX1_2,
    EnnemyFX2_2,
    Ennemy_3,
    EnnemyFX1_3,
    EnnemyFX2_3,
    Background,
    BackgroundParticles1,
    BackgroundParticles2,
    Button,
    InactiveButton
}
```

ColorName is used to create color palettes (each Enum element corresponds to a specific color in my game) and GlobalColor is used to attach colors to GameObjects, Ennemy appears only once because the ennemies color is chosen randomly between the three from ColorName.
In a generic ColoriseBase script (it's the base of all Colorise script, in charge to color different component accordingly to a color of the current palette, there exists ColoriseSprite, ColoriseParticleSystem and ColoriseCamera, all inheriting from ColoriseBase) I have the following code:
`[SerializeField] private GlobalColor color;` to be able to choose the color of my component directly in the inspector.
To convert this GlobalColor to a ColorName (to find the correct color in the current palette) I'm using reflection:

```
protected ColorName GlobalColorToColorName(GlobalColor color)
{
    string randomEnnemy = "";
    if (color == Ennemy || color == EnnemyFX1 || color == EnnemyFX2)
    {
        EnnemyIdentity ennemyIdentity = GetComponentInParent<EnnemyIdentity>();
        if (ennemyIdentity != null)
            randomEnnemy = string.Format("_%s", ennemyIdentity.EnnemyType.ToString());
        else
            throw new MissingComponentException("An ennemy needs to have an EnnemyIdentity script attached to it.");
    }
    print(Enum.GetName(typeof(GlobalColor), color));
    string name = Enum.GetName(typeof(GlobalColor), color);
    var type = typeof(ColorName);
    return (ColorName)type.GetProperty(name + randomEnnemy).GetValue(null);
}
```

The print method is for debugging purposes. However, an Exception is thrown when i launch my game:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
ColoriseBase`1[E].GlobalColorToColorName (GlobalColor color) (at Assets/Scripts/Color/ColoriseBase.cs:56)
ColoriseBase`1[E].get_Color () (at Assets/Scripts/Color/ColoriseBase.cs:10)
```

I tried to find the error and I found out that my variable `GlobalColor color`in `ColoriseBase` is not equal to the value I give in the inspector. If in the inspector I initialize it at `Player`(which index == 0) this variable will have the index 12, no member of `GlobalColor`has this index, which causes the Exception.

Comment: need to show how `GlobalColorToColorName` is called. According to the error you are not passing the argument `GlobalColor color` into the method

Comment: @rustyBucketBay no, needs to be something else. `GlobalColor` is an `enum` (value type) and therefore can never be `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% but pretty sure the error comes from

```
type.GetProperty
```

since your type is an `enum` it has no properties, it has only values. And most probably this returns `null` and therefore later the `GetValue` causes the exception.

What you probably would rather use is [`Enum.Parse<TEnum>(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.parse) like e.g. (assuming the rest of it works as expected)

```
return Enum.Parse<ColorName>(name + randomEnnemy);
```

---

For future issues and questions: Please point out which line the exception is thrown from.

And in general for debugging purposes avoid longer chained accesses like you had in

```
return (ColorName)type.GetProperty(name + randomEnnemy).GetValue(null);
```

You lose or gain nothing by having it all in a line, well, except as said it is worse for debugging it. You can as well write it as

```
var fullName = name + randomEnnemy;
var property = type.GetProperty(fullName);
return (ColorName) property.GetValue(null);
```

but this way you can better debug at which point exactly it is failing when [Debugging your code with breakpoints](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks *derHugo* I found out a solution, here's my new `GlobalColorToColorName`method:

```
protected ColorName GlobalColorToColorName(GlobalColor color)
{
    string name = color.ToString();
    if (color == Ennemy || color == EnnemyFX1 || color == EnnemyFX2)
    {
        string randomEnnemy;
        EnnemyIdentity ennemyIdentity = GetComponentInParent<EnnemyIdentity>();
        if (ennemyIdentity != null)
            randomEnnemy = string.Format("_%s", ennemyIdentity.EnnemyType.ToString());
        else
            throw new MissingComponentException("An ennemy needs to have an EnnemyIdentity script attached to it.");
        name += randomEnnemy;
    }
    return (ColorName)Enum.Parse(typeof(ColorName), name);
}
```

Comment: You should really rather use the generic version I showed in my answer ;) `Enum.Parse<ColorName>(name + randomEnnemy);`

Comment: Thanks a lot but did you mean Enum.TryParse(name, out aColorNameVariable); ? (It is generic)

Comment: No, as already written twice I mean `Enum.Parse<ColorName>(name)` ;) you can of course also use `Enum.TryParse<T>(string, out T)` which is also generic yes